# How to convert oracle backup status report output in text file to html using shell script?

Tags: html, oracle, shell

I have a output text file as follows.

```
SESSION_KEY INPUT_TYPE    STATUS          START_TIME     END_TIME
 ----------- ------------- ----------------------- -------------- --------------
123 DB FULL   COMPLETED       08/01/17 00:19 08/01/17 00:21
130 DB FULL   COMPLETED       08/01/17 12:49 08/01/17 12:52


SESSION_KEY INPUT_TYPE    STATUS          START_TIME     END_TIME
----------- ------------- ----------------------- -------------- --------------
  1 DB FULL   COMPLETED       08/01/17 16:18 08/01/17 16:23


  SESSION_KEY INPUT_TYPE      STATUS          START_TIME     END_TIME
  ----------- ------------- ----------------------- -------------- --------------
  1 DB FULL   FAILED          08/01/17 15:13 08/01/17 15:16
  4 DB FULL   FAILED          08/01/17 15:17 08/01/17 15:17
  6 DB FULL   FAILED          08/01/17 15:25
 14 DB FULL   COMPLETED       08/01/17 16:22 08/01/17 16:25
```

The above output need to convert to HTML page. Can you please assist to how to convert backup status report to html?. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_seven.htm#SQPUG017) might be helpful.

Comment: And also I need to append multiple instance status report in html into a single html with instance name  @Nitish

Comment: It works. Thanks for your information . 

Thank you sooooo much @Nitish. You save a big time for me..

Comment: In that html output i need to remove duplicate header. Is it possible? @Nitish

Comment: If you are running multiple queries for the report, you can combine them using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Yep. I am using multiple query. And my query is

select a.instance_name AS INSTANCE_NAME, b.INPUT_TYPE , b.STATUS, To_char(b.START_TIME, 'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') AS START_TIME, To_char(b.END_TIME,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') AS END_TIME FROM v\\$instance a, v\\$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS b WHERE trunc(b.start_time)=trunc(sysdate-1);

Comment: That is just a single query.

Comment: I need to merge instance and RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS table...

I need the data as instance_name, input_type, status, start_time, end_time

Comment: I think you need to ask that as a separate question with all the information of what you have done till now. That way you'll be able to reach more people who can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151027/discussion-between-suganthan-raj-and-nitish).

Comment: I cannot. No access to chat here.

Comment: I have used CROSS JOIN to merge two tables. but still In that html output displaying  duplicate header for multiple instance status report. Is it possible to remove duplicate ? Please assists @Nitish